# mysql database tables design

Tags: sql

I have to design a database for an advert site.
Until now this is the design i came up with:

> Administrator(Id,Name,Password)
>
> Advert(Advert_Id,Title,Description,Category,User,Date_created,Picture,Type)
>
> User(User_Id, Name ,Phone,email,Address)
>
> Category(Cat_id,Cat_Name)
>
> Type(Id,Type_Name)
>
> Picture(Picture_Id,Name)

The administrator refers to to the person that will manage the site.

The type refers to the type of the advert: selling, buying etc.

I must have minimum 5 tables at least 2 one to many relationships and at least one many to many relationship. The problem is that I can't find a many to many relationship that would make sense.

Comment: An advert could have multiple categories; and each category would have multiple adverts

Comment: From where did the requirements you specified come?

Comment: Nothing wrong with homework questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: The requirements were given by the teacher for the project i have to make.I just cant think of a many to many relationship that would make sense.

Comment: Nothing wrong with homework, it's still a coding question.

Comment: Pictures jumps out to me as a good candidate: each advert could have multiple pictures/images, and one image could be used for multiple adverts (e.g., picture of a dog for a dog food advert and a flea collar advert).

Answer (score 0):

If an advertisement can have more than one category, then advertisements and category would be many to many.

If an ad can have more than one picture and a picture can be used in more than one ad, ads and pictures would be many to many.

However, you have to know the business rules.  None of us will.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dan mentioned on the answer, you have to know the Business Rules. It's a project for a class, so the business rules might be flexible, I remember back in college, for example, they would tell us that if a client wanted to have advertisement be of at least one category, but could have up to 3 or 4 different categories, that changes your DB structure a lot.

An advertisement can also have many pictures, not just one. It can even have some videos, and many of them as well. Make sure you clarify well the Business Rules and that you understand them fully, as in a real life situation, that can represent either the success of your project or the failure of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Indeed i am allowed use my own set of business rules so they are very flexible from this point of view.

Comment: If I may recommend, try and go for a challenge, don't stay with just the easy stuff. That will get you a lot of practice for when you go out there and face the real life projects, where tight deadlines and challenges are just everywhere to be found. An advice because I had it the hard way :)